# spl-token-cli: how to fix this error

Tags: spl-token, token-2022, spl-associated-token-account, spl-token-cli

```
$ spl-token transfer --expected-fee 0.000005 ++m+++++++++++++++++2u++ 100000 destination.json
Transfer 100000 tokens
  Sender: ++zt++++++++++++++++++Dw++
  Recipient: ++LN+++++++++++++++++++75++
**Error: "Error:** The recipient address is not funded. Add `--allow-unfunded-recipient` to complete the transfer."
```

i  hide my wallet address for security reason

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you send a token to another address you the other wallet needs to have a token account to save these tokens. These token accounts costs some sol in rent to be saved on the blockchain.

Someone needs to pay for this.
So if you add the flag

```
--allow-unfunded-recipient
```

to your transfer you pay for the token account on the other side. So just add it to the end of your command